# Why is this returning unidentified even when I manually assign it for testing?

Tags: php, json, post, curl, http-post

This always throws the error that none of those params are valid. For example: `Undefined index: dataNL`

Receiving Code:

```
$ajax_arrayBTF = $_POST['dataBTF'];
$ajax_arrayLI = $_POST['dataLI'];
$ajax_arrayLS = $_POST['dataLS'];
$ajax_arrayNL = $_POST['dataNL'];
$agent_id = $_POST['agent'];
```

Here is the calling code I am using:

```
$data = array(
    "dataBTF" => "0",
    "dataNL" => "0",
    "dataLS" => "0",
    "dataLI" =>  "0",
    "agent" => "53" 
);

$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
echo  $data_string;
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost/site1/backend/scripts/oppCAL.php');                                                                      
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");                                                                     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);                                                                  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADERS, array('Content-Type: application/json'));                                                                  
echo curl_exec($ch);
```

I don't get why this is happening, because I am MANUALLY assigning it. So it is valid.  `echo      $data_string;`  displays

```
{"dataBTF":"0","dataNL":"0","dataLS":"0","dataLI":"0","agent":"53"}
```

Just like it should.. I decided to go with JSON, but even that is not working. CURL is enabled. What am I missing here?

EDIT:

When ajax was calling there was no issue. My ajax was:

```
$.ajax(
          {
            type: 'post',
            url: 'scripts/oppCAL.php',
            data: 
            {
              dataBTF:  $array_jsBTF,
              dataLI:   $array_jsLI,
              dataLS:   $array_jsLS,
              dataNL:   $array_jsNL,
              agent:    $agent_id
            },
            success: function(e) 
            {
              console.log("done:");

            } //success
          }); // ajax
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP doesn't parse JSON body data, only form encoded, like your jQuery ajax call sends. It looks something like this:

```
dataBTF=0&dataLI=0&dataLS=0&dataNL=0&agent=0
```

When receiving JSON, you can use something like this to get the data:

```
$body = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($body, true);
```